# Why does stream.max() result differ when using comparator in ascending vs descending order?

Tags: java, java-stream, comparator

I have the code setup below and I'm a bit confused why the stream.max() returns a different result when Comparator is set up to sort in ascending vs descending order. I know how comparators work to sort an array, but not very clear how max and comparator work with a stream.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Cat c1 = new Cat(5);
        Cat c2 = new Cat(6);
        Cat c3 = new Cat(7);

        ArrayList<Cat> arr = new ArrayList<Cat>();
        arr.add(c1);
        arr.add(c2);
        arr.add(c3);
        
        Optional<Cat> cMax = findMax(arr);
        System.out.println(cMax.get().age);

    }
    
    public static Optional<Cat> findMax(ArrayList<Cat> arr) {
        return arr.stream()
          .max((Cat a, Cat b) -> {
            return b.age - a.age;
            // versus a.age - b.age
      });
    }
}

class Cat{
    int age;
    Cat(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried, but my expectation would be that `max(a-b)` is `min(b-a)`

Comment: Right `b.age - a.age` returns 5 and `a.age - b.age` returns 7

Comment: You can think about it as if the comparator answers the question "is a larger than b?" by returning a positive number (yes) or a negative one (no). And if you systematically "lie", searching for a maximum will actually find the minimum.

Comment: order of operation between the max function and the comparator is confusing. is the `max` function here keeping track of the max between every pair compared in the stream?

Answer (score 4):

The question is, why do you expect the same result when you give the method two different comparators, one in natural order and the other in reverse?

If you call the operation `max` with a comparator, you implicitly define with the comparator which object should be the largest. In other words, you want the stream to be sorted by the comparator and you want the last element. If it were a list, it is easy to understand why different results come out when you say sort the list and give me the last object. The last object depends on whether you sort in ascending or descending order.

Maybe the name of the method is misleading. It should have been called `maxBy` and not simply `max`. With age as in your example it leads to misunderstandings. Max is not the mathematicaly maximum number but max according to your definition / comparator. Theoretically you could also have passed a name comparator, assuming your class had a field name:

```
List<Cat> myCatList = List.of(new Cat("Jane"), new Cat("Dave"), new Cat("Susane"),);

....

public static Optional<Cat> findMax(ArrayList<Cat> arr) {
    return arr.stream()
      .max((Cat a, Cat b) -> {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
  });
}
```

and you would have had Susane as result although it probably makes no sense without context to say the cat with the name Susane is the max cat.

I don't want to say that sorting in reverse order doesn't make sense. Take school grades for example. In many countries, school grades are letters and A is the best and F is the worst. But in natural order the letter F is bigger. In such case, just as an example, if you want to get from a stream of student objects the one with the best grade, i.e. `max(grades_comparator)`, you don't want to have the worst student with the f but the best one with the grade a. There you pass a reversed comparator.

Apart from that, you should prefer existing methods for comparison instead of using math tricks to achieve the sorting. In your example with the simple numbers it is not necessary, but with large numbers you may unintentionally get an overflow if your values are close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and your program delivers strange results. So better :

```
public static Optional<Cat> findMax(ArrayList<Cat> arr) {
    return arr.stream()
      .max((Cat a, Cat b) -> {
        return Integer.compare(a.age, b.age);
  });
}
```

Or, if you are going to experiment with streams api anyway, you should also use comparator interface and method reference, which makes the whole thing even more readable:

```
public static Optional<Cat> findMax(ArrayList<Cat> arr) {
    return arr.stream()
              .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Cat::getAge));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a bit of magical thinking on your side, but [`Comparator.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) has a very simple, one-line summary:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a *negative integer*, zero, or a **positive integer** as the first argument is *less than*, equal to, or **greater than** the second.

This is what `max()` and `min()` expect from the comparator you provide them, and thus `(Cat a, Cat b) -> a.age - b.age` will provide the "natural" maximum and minimum when supplied to them. However you can very well do anything else in the comparator, just then the result will reflect that kind of comparison, like doing the complete opposite of their names with the `b-a` variant.

It's just a mere convenience that any kind of integer is accepted, but only their relation to 0 gets actually used.

[`ReferencePipeline.java`](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/94318f9185757cc33d2b8d527d36be26ac6b7582/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#L581) has the actual implementation, and it really uses `reduce()` as the [documentation promises](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) ("*This is a special case of a reduction.*").

> ```
> @Override
> public final Optional<P_OUT> max(Comparator<? super P_OUT> comparator) {
>     return reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(comparator));
> }
> ```

[`BinaryOperator.java`](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/94318f9185757cc33d2b8d527d36be26ac6b7582/src/share/classes/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.java#L72) has `maxBy()`, creating a function which picks the larger value based on the supplied comparator:

> ```
> public static <T> BinaryOperator<T> maxBy(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
>     Objects.requireNonNull(comparator);
>     return (a, b) -> comparator.compare(a, b) >= 0 ? a : b;
> }
> ```